# AS3 Call to possibly undefined method with a static type Class error i can't fix

Tags: actionscript-3

i am following a game tutorial but making some modifications. to add multiple levels i added instance's but this screwed up more then i can fix.

every level points can be made and if you die those points should be seen on the gameoverscreen.

the level code

```
    package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;


public class LevelEen extends MovieClip 
{
    public var gerardJoling : GerardJoling;
    public var geerTimer:Timer;
    public var geerGame : GeerGame;
    public var geer_score:GeerScore;
    public static var instance:LevelEen;

    public var gameOverScherm:GameOverScherm;
    public var levelEen:LevelEen;

    public var pattys:Array;        

    public var enemy:VrouwVijand;

    public var volumeAdjust:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
    public var channelNogniet:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    public var channelScore:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    public var Nogniet:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Sounds/Gerard Joling - Het is nog niet voorbij.mp3");
    public var Score:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Sounds/10046_1361186725.mp3");
    public var noMoreNogniet:Sound = new Sound(Nogniet);
    public var noMoreScore:Sound = new Sound(Score);

    public function LevelEen() 
    {
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        volumeAdjust.volume = 1;
        channelNogniet = noMoreNogniet.play(0,10);
        channelNogniet.soundTransform = volumeAdjust;

        gerardJoling = new GerardJoling();
        addChild(gerardJoling);
        gerardJoling.x = mouseX;
        gerardJoling.y = mouseY;

        pattys = new Array();

        geerTimer = new Timer( 25 );
        geerTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, geerInteractie);
        geerTimer.start();
    }

    public function geerInteractie( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
    {
        if ( Math.random() < 0.04 )
        {
            var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 550;
            var vrouwVijand:VrouwVijand = new VrouwVijand( randomX, -40 );
            pattys.push(vrouwVijand);
            addChild(vrouwVijand);
            geer_score.addToValue( 0 );
        }

        gerardJoling.x = mouseX;
        gerardJoling.y = mouseY;

        var i:int = pattys.length - 1;
        var enemy:VrouwVijand;
        var finalScore:Number = getFinalScore();

        while ( i > -1 )
        {
            enemy = pattys[i];
            enemy.dalen();
            if ( gerardJoling.hitTestObject(enemy) ) 
            {
                geerTimer.stop();
                SoundMixer.stopAll();
                GameOverScherm.setFinalScore( finalScore );
                GeerGame.instance.switchScreen( "GameOverScherm" );
                trace (geer_score.currentValue);
            }

            if ( enemy.y > 400 )
            {
                removeChild( enemy );
                pattys.splice( i, 1 );
                geer_score.addToValue( 10 );
                channelScore = noMoreScore.play(0,1);
            }

            if (geer_score.currentValue > 40)
            {
                geerTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, geerInteractie);
                GeerGame.instance.switchScreen( "LevelTwee" );
            }

            i = i - 1;
        }

    }
    public function getFinalScore():Number
    {
        return geer_score.currentValue;
    }
}}
```

here a score is calculated in a other class, but the setFinalScore en getFinalscore also have to do there job to get the final score and send it to the gameoverscherm

```
    package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;


public class GameOverScherm extends MovieClip
{
    public var gameOverScherm:GameOverScherm;
    public var levelEen:LevelEen;
    public var volumeAdjust:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
    public var channelGeer:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    public var Geer:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Sounds/Gerard Joling heeft er geen kracht meer voor1.mp3");
    public var noMoreGeer:Sound = new Sound(Geer);

    public var finalScore:TextField;

    public function GameOverScherm()
    {
        opnieuw_button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickOpnieuw );
        menu_button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu );
        volumeAdjust.volume = 1;
        channelGeer = noMoreGeer.play(0,1);
        channelGeer.soundTransform = volumeAdjust;

    }

    public function onClickOpnieuw( mouseEvent:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        GeerGame.instance.switchScreen( "LevelEen" );
        gameOverScherm = null;
    }

    public function onClickMenu( mouseEvent:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        GeerGame.instance.switchScreen( "StartScherm" );
        gameOverScherm = null;
    }
    public function setFinalScore( scoreValue:Number ):void
    {
        finalScore.text = scoreValue.toString();
    }
}}
```

this is the error i get and i cant seem to figure out how to fix it and make the final score  appear on the gameoverscreen

```
C:\Users\Ian-w\Dropbox\game\GeerGame\LevelEen.as, Line 87   1061: Call to a possibly undefined method setFinalScore through a reference with static type Class.
```

i really hope someone can help me on here, have been stuck on this for a few days

NEWWWW

made the changes and now if i trace(scoreValue) in class GameOverScherm the function setFinalScore i get a response with the correct score, but

```
    public function setFinalScore( scoreValue:Number ):void
{
    finalScore.text = scoreValue.toString();
    trace(scoreValue)
}
```

in the GameOverScherm screen the dynamic tekst field name:finalScore does not change value...

aperently i cant post a image so i only post the link http://s29.postimg.org/jwxu6rlfr/Untitled.jpg

what did i do wronge? do i need to update the screen after pusinh the score to the field or something??

Comment: Came across a new problem now i fixed the others:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several errors in your code, tu use this :

```
GameOverScherm.setFinalScore( finalScore );
```

you would have to change several things in your class "GameOverScherm" to use the function "setFinalScore" as a static method. I don't think that what you wanted, i see you have :

```
public var gameOverScherm:GameOverScherm;
```

Which seems like you wanted to create some sort of "singleton pattern". If so, you need to put this variable as static, then "gameOverScherm" should be set as "gameOverScherm = this" somewhere in your class. This way you would change the line inside "LevelEen" :

GameOverScherm.gameOverScherm.setFinalScore( finalScore );

There is many ways to correct this depending on your code (with or without the use of static methods/variables), but your error say that there is no static function named "setFinalScore". I suggest you to take a look at what's the static word means and how / why to use it.

Comment: thank you very much, i will read up on static functions and make some changes!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `setFinalScore()` from `GameOverScherm` as though it were a publicly visible static function. Since there is no publicly available function of that name available it returns undefined.

[Here](https://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-quick-tip-e28093-when-to-use-static-properties-and-methods--active-7832) is a good write up on how static functions work and when to use them.

It looks like you have a `gameOverScherm` variable in `LevelEen` but haven't created a new instance of the `GameOverScherm` class. You could use this variable to achieve what you're trying to do. You'll need to create a new instance of `GameOverScherm` in an appropriate place like so:

```
gameOverScherm = new GameOverScherm();
```

so you can access its public functions like so:

```
gameOverScherm.setFinalScore(finalScore);
```

Comment: thank you for the link, easyer than having to google it:D
and i will put in the instance!